# Should `copy-region-as-kill` be modified to include `(setq transient-mark-mode nil)`?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When using the `post-command-hook` following `copy-region-as-kill` and the `post-command-hook` includes a test for `region-active-p`, that test returns positive because `transient-mark-mode` has not yet been returned to `nil`.

Is the `post-command-hook` designed to act upon what was in existence *before* `this-command` was executed, or should the `post-command-hook` be looking at the world as if `this-command` has already run its course?

---

**EDIT**:  My apologies for not specifying that I am using the latest version of Emacs Trunk. Here is the current function that performs the test:

```
(defun region-active-p ()
  (and transient-mark-mode mark-active (mark)))
```

Here is the message from `M-x emacs-version`:

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0,
  NS appkit-1038.36 Version 10.6.8 (Build 10K549)) of 2014-06-01 on MP.local
```

---

Here is an example of the active region that hypothetically may need to be copied using `copy-region-as-kill`, and tested for while the `post-command-hook` is running.  [That way, the new overlays can be placed with calculations assuming there is no active region.]  In the context of this example, I need the test to return `nil` when `this-command` equals `copy-region-as-kill` and one way to accomplish that goal is to modify `copy-region-as-kill` to include `(setq transient-mark-mode nil)` at the tail end of the function.  However, I hesitate to modify a staple function like `copy-region-as-kill`.  [It wouldn't make much sense (in my opinion) to include conditions that state if `region-active-p` and `this-command` equals `copy-region-as-kill`, then pretend the region isn't active.]

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/region_active_p_example.png))</sub>

Comment: This behavior is the same in older Emacsen.  Explain why you think you need to use `region-active-p` in `post-command-hook`.

Comment: I am using functions like shift + arrow and shift + forward / backward-word to select a region.  While I am doing that, I have a horizontal and vertical ruler being drawn (cross-hairs) to show me what line I am on and what cursor position.  `region-active-p` is used to determine what types of overlays to use inside and outside the active region.  When I copy the region, the cross-hairs readjust to life with no region.  I felt bad modifying a staple function such as `copy-region-as-kill` without understanding  whether the `post-command-hook` should use life before or after `this-command`.

Comment: In addition to cross-hairs, I also have end-of-line indicators (overlays) -- pilcrows which match the color of the active region, or take on a different color if outside the active region.  [I forgot to put an @Stefan in the prior comment, so here it is.  :)]

Comment: Hmmm.  Can you read the docs I linked in my answer and say why deactivate-mark doesn't work for you and you must use region-active-p?  IOW deactivate-mark declares that the mark should be deactivated after the command loop finishes, so you can check it in post-command-hook to get the new state of the mark.

Comment: @event_jr -- I'd be happy to spend some more time on the issue, including reading the referenced docs, and report back -- thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**INITIAL DRAFT** (June 4, 2014):  After looking at the documentation and the helpful comments and answers in this thread, I'm strongly leaning in favor of a new test specifically designed to be used inside the `post-command-hook`.  This will avoid modifying the core / staple functions of `kill-region`, `copy-region-as-kill`, and `yank`.  Since the new function will be included in my own library for the minor-mode, there is no reason why I can't base some of the basic calculations on said function.  The *function* entitled `deactivate-mark` in `simple.el` uses `(setq mark-active nil)` and `(setq transient-mark-mode nil)`, so there is no reason why I can't use them also in my own custom function.

- Special thanks to @Andreas Röhler, @event_jr, and @Stefan -- greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** (June 5, 2014):  Revised initial draft to merely test conditions, rather than setting either of the variables (`mark-active` or `transient-mark-mode`) to `nil`.

```lisp
(defun lawlist-region-active-p ()
"Custom test to determine whether the region is presently active; AND,
whether the region will be active when the `post-command-hook` finishes."
  (cond
    ((memq this-command '(
        self-insert-command
        delete-backward-char
        delete-forward-char
        kill-region
        delete-region
        copy-region-as-kill
        yank
        kill-word
        lawlist-copy-selected-region
        lawlist-kill-word
        lawlist-yank ))
      nil)
    ((and transient-mark-mode mark-active (mark)))))

(defun test-lawlist-region-active-p ()
  (cond
    ((lawlist-region-active-p)
      (message "ACTIVE region."))
    ((not (lawlist-region-active-p))
      (message "NOT active region."))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'test-lawlist-region-active-p)
```

Comment: BTW maybe you should not employ user-level commands -- which may do a lot of things behind the scene -- but dig deeper in. For example consider delete-region etc.

Answer (score 2):

`transient-mark-mode` has nothing to do with it.  Check `deactivate-mark` instead.

To wit, you can't use `region-active-p` in a post-command-hook, but instead check the value of the `deactivate-mark` variable see [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html).

Comment: My apologies for not specifying that I am using the latest version of Emacs Trunk.  Here is the current function that performs the test:  `(defun region-active-p () (and transient-mark-mode mark-active (mark)))`  Here is the message from `M-x emacs-version`:  `GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS appkit-1038.36 Version 10.6.8 (Build 10K549)) of 2014-06-01 on MP.local`

Comment: `transient-mark-mode` should not be modified by any command.  It's the second part of the `and` clause that's giving you the unexpected result.

Comment: `copy-region-as-kill` contains `(setq deactivate-mark t)` towards the end of the function -- in the latest version of Emacs Trunk.

Comment: Correct.  So use it?  You should really read the docs I linked.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation can only be fixed by using `(setq transient-mark-mode nil)` -- the question is whether the default behavior is appropriate and why.

Comment: I'm going to leave this question open until I do some more reading/experimenting and try to gain a better understanding of what is happening.  It seems to me that just about everything under the sun triggers `deactivate-mark`, but not cursor movement.  I still don't see how testing for `deactivate-mark` could be useful.  `(defun test () (cond (deactivate-mark (message "deactivate-mark: %s" deactivate-mark)) ((not deactivate-mark) (message "not deactivate-mark:  %s" deactivate-mark)))) (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'test)`  I think I will need to write a new `region-active-p` for my minor-mode.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure there is no active region after running

```
(deactivate-mark t)
```

should do the trick. Why not finish the command in question with it, instead employing as a `post-command-hook`?

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand that there is a function *and* a variable with the same name.  The function looks like it will be more useful than the variable.  What I may do is create a new function similar to `region-active-p` and put in it something like `(when (memq this-command my-list-of-special-functions) . . .` and create a variable list of functions for things like `copy-region-as-kill` and a custom `yank` function (for pasting code inside an active region); and, then use `(deactivate-mark t)`.  At least that way, I'm not going to be modifying key / staple Emacs functions.

Comment: I need to lay new overlays before a redisplay occurs so that I don't see a *naked* buffer without overlays -- I remove the prior overlays at the outset of the `post-command-hook`.  I think something the following should do the trick:  `(defun lawlist-region-active-p () (when (memq this-command '(kill-region copy-region-as-kill )) (deactivate-mark t)) (and transient-mark-mode mark-active (mark)))`